# NSFetchedResultsController with Distinct Results in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, core-data

If I understand correctly you have to use setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType to allow setReturnsDistinctResults to work.

When I don't use setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType I don't get distinct results as expected.

When I do use it I get:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSKnownKeysDictionary1 objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I want the distinct results to populate a UITableViewCell:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {





LocationInfo *info  = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] ;
cell.textLabel.text =  info.fieldname;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@",
                             info.date, info.acres, info.comments];
```

}

I'm using a simple NSFetchedResultsController with the setResultType set to NSDictionaryResultType:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"fieldname"]];



NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"fieldname" ascending:NO];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];



 [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fieldname"]];
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];




NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:moc sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:@"Root"];

_fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

Am I improperly feeding the configureCell? What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: By "change tracking", the error is referring to the FRC's process of calling its delegate whenever the relevant NSManagedObjects in its context change.  Since you are using NSDictionaryResultType, the fetch returns an array of dictionaries, which does not change even if the objects in the context change.  To avoid the error, just set the delegate to nil.

Comment: @pbasdf I did this:  _fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil; I get this now: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter

Comment: What line does that error occur on?  It suggests your managedObjectContext is nil - which implies a more fundamental problem with your CoreData stack.